# Moving Data from Azure Blob Storage to Azure Synapse(Sql dedicated pools)

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, polybase

I have a requirement to move Azure Blob Storage data to Azure Synapse (SQL dedicated pools).
Azure Blob Storage container has around 850 Gb of data(in form of multiple json files). I have created a Synapse pipeline . I have used polybase to move the data from blob storage to SQL dedicated pools. In case of Polybase we would need a staging environment for which i have used a staging blob container.

Azure Blob storage -> staging container -> SQL dedicated pool(Azure Synapse)

I have not kept any restrictions on DIU and parallel processing so it uses 32 DIU and parallel goes processing numbers goes upto 120-130 .

first stage is completed in 5 hrs moving 850gb of data to staging container but the second stage it still runs for 15 hours now but not yet completed and DIU i can see is 2 and parallel processing 1 .

Do i need to explicitly specify the DIU and parallel processing .
Is there any better way to do this except polybase.

Comment: What DWU is your SQL dedicated pool at?  What resource class is associated with the user running this load?  What other activity is going on in the SQL pool (concurrency, check for blocking), are you doing a `for each file` (pseudocode) in the Synapse pipeline (bad) or just Copy activity.  What is the distribution and indexing choice in the target table?  Are the staging storage account and Synapse workspace in the same region?

Comment: @wBob Please find the details below 


DWU - 2500  |
just copy activity in the synapse pipeline   |
distribution and index are the default in target table  |
Staging storage account and synapse workspace - in same region   |
Resource class associated - no clue on this , can you help here

Comment: @wBob Can you please help me how to check if anything is blocking as no other activity is running in sql pool. Also the Storage account which has the blob container has no hierarchical name space enabled so the ADLSGen2 used while creating synapse workspace is on another Storage account in the same region

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 keys points missing from  your question:

1. Why are you using Staging Table?
2. Do you need to perform any transformation on the data?
3. Why your staging table is in Blob Storage?

As per the best approach:

> It is best practice to load data into a staging table. **Staging tables
> allow you to handle errors without interfering with the production
> tables.** A staging table also gives you the opportunity to **use SQL pool
> built-in distributed query processing capabilities for data
> transformations before inserting the data into production tables.**

So, as you haven't mentioned if your approach is **Extract, Transform and Load (ETL)** or **Extract, Load and Transform (ELT)**; reason for staging table isn't clear. If your approach is ETL, staging is good else it is not required.

**Secondly, Staging Tables should be in SQL Pool, not in blob storage.**

Before loading the data in Staging Table, **you need to define external tables in your data warehouse.** PolyBase uses external tables to define and access the data in Azure Storage. An external table is similar to a database view. The external table contains the table schema and points to data that is stored outside the data warehouse.

You also need to take care of **resource class** and **distribution method**. Refer this [third-party article](https://sql-stijn.com/2020/12/16/azure-synapse-sql-pools-loading-staging-tables/) to know more about these 2 workload management terminologies.

As there are so many parameters you need to consider to find out what exactly the issue is, I suggest you to first go through important official documents and then make appropriate changes in your architecture.

Helpful links:

[Design a PolyBase data loading strategy for dedicated SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/load-data-overview#4-load-the-data-into-dedicated-sql-pool-staging-tables-using-polybase)

[Workload management with resource classes in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/resource-classes-for-workload-management)

[Best practices for loading data into a dedicated SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/data-loading-best-practices)

Comment: My requirement is to copy the data present in Azure blob containers to Sql dedicated pool , no transformations required. As i am using polybase it does not allow to copy the data instead of staging containers , so i was using Azure storage for staging

Comment: refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/load-data-wideworldimportersdw

Comment: I am now trying to use the external tables to move data from blob to synapse dedicated pool but when i try to declare the FileFormat it gives errors 



```
-- Create an external file format for JSON files.
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT file_format_name  
WITH (  
    FORMAT_TYPE = JSON  
     [ , DATA_COMPRESSION = {  
        'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec'  
      | 'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec'      
      | 'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec'  }  
    ]); 
```
Can you please help here